# Querying Git for stored username and email

Tags: git

Just a quick question. I just wanted to see which username and email Git has stored for me (I set this up a good time ago) but when I type `git config user.name` the prompt just reappears on the next line with no other results, and when I type: `git config --list` I get `credential.helper=osxkeychain` returned, and not my username, email or anything else.
Sorry but I am also quite inexperienced with the command line - can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Maybe you have an alias? Post the content of your `.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sry i cant write a comment.

@phil

`--global` is not needed.
if type `git config --list` it would show the `--local`, `--global` and `--system` config in one list.

@cheznead

set a new user.name does it work ?

```
git config --global user.name 'YourUserName'



git config --global --edit
```

and u can edit with vi

did u know the syntax for vi ? https://ss64.com/vi.html

for edit push the 'Insert' or 'i' button on Keyboard

for save 'ESC' + ':qw'

Comment: Wow, it will `--list` everything even without `--global`... that's what I get for not RTFMing properly I guess.

Comment: Hey, I brought up the user configuration file in terminal and I cannot edit it or get back to the command line. I will open a new terminal window, but do you know how to edit that configuration file from the command line?

Comment: Hey, so I changed username using git config --global user.name 'YourUserName' command, and then checked it calling git config --global --list and it just brought up the new username only.

Comment: ok - next issue, where is the damn insert button on the macbook pro?

Comment: if you want edit the config file in terminal you have to use vi syntax.
here for vi:
https://ss64.com/vi.html

and sry you can Start the Insert Mode with 'i' :)

Comment: Awesome! This is harder than I thought! Thanks a lot for sticking with it.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Thanks to something I learned from @JayDee today, this answer is now useless except for it's comments maybe.

---

Since your name and email probably won't vary for each repository, you most likely stored it in the *global* config accessible via the `--global` flag.

```
git config --global --list
```

Comment: "your name and email won't vary for each repository" is completely false statement.

Comment: Well, yes, both *can* vary for each repository. I've rephrased it since it's very likely OP has put it in the global config either way.

Comment: Tried this command: Got back "fatal: unable to read config file '/Users/devwind/.gitconfig': No such file or directory"

Comment: I can see username and email when I run a commit with a message though. It has just taken my name and created an email address automatically. I ran  git config --global --edit and this brings up my configuration file. How do I edit this?